# TeamCity and Git

Tags: .net, git, teamcity

I'm having trouble setting up Teamcity and Git. I have a git repo checked out to a directory. My "clone repository to" setting in Teamcity VCS root is set to the same directory. When I run the build, I get the error

```
The ref 'refs/heads/master' could not be resolved
```

Apparently because it deleted the .git directory, and/or possibly moved the files in /.git to the parent directory.

I'm obviously misunderstanding some part of this process, but which? Thanks.

Comment: Is the error from TeamCity or your build script?

Comment: It's from TeamCity, before the build occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try leave "Clone repository to" field empty, it should work this way. "Clone repository to" points to the directory where TeamCity clones remote repository. If you leave it empty TeamCity will use default location (folder inside ~/.BuildServer/system/caches/git). I think an error occurs because before cloning, TeamCity cleans up specified dir.

Comment: Thank you - that appears to be it. I thought TeamCity deployed directly to the website directory, not that it needed another step to move the files.